# Clean code: consequences of short methods with few parameters

Tags: object-oriented, clean-code

Recently during a code review I came across code, written by a new colleague, which contains a pattern with a smell. I suspect that my colleague's decisions are based on rules proposed by the famous Clean Code book (and perhaps by other similar books as well).

It is my understanding that the class constructor is entirely responsible for the creation of a valid object and that its main task is the assignment of an object's (private) properties. It could of course occur that optional property values may be set by methods other than the class constructor, but such situations are rather rare (although not necessarily wrong, provided that the rest of the class takes into account such a property's optionality). This is important, because it allows to ensure that the object is always in a valid state.

However, in the code that I encountered, most property values are actually set by other methods than the constructor. Values that result from calculations are assigned to properties to be used inside several private methods throughout the class. The author seemingly uses class properties as if they were global variables that should be accessible throughout the class, instead of parameterizing these values to the functions that need them. Additionally, the methods of the class should be called in a specific order, because the class won't do much otherwise.

I suspect that this code has been inspired by the advice to keep methods short (<=5 lines of code), to avoid large parameter lists (<3 parameters) and that constructors must not do work (such as performing a calculation of some sort that is essential for the validity of the object).

Now of course I could make a case against this pattern if I can prove that all kinds of undefined errors potentially arise when methods are not called in a specific order. However, I predict that the response to this is going to be adding validations which verify that properties must be set once methods are called that need those properties to be set.

I would however rather propose to completely change the code, so that the class becomes a blue print to an actual object, rather than a series of methods which should be called (procedurally) in a specific order.

I feel that the code that I encountered smells. In fact, I believe there exists a rather clear distinction as to when to save a value in a class property and when to put it into a parameter for a different method to use - I don't really believe they can be alternatives to one another. I am looking for the words for this distinction.

Comment: 1.  Playing devil's advocate for a moment... *Does the code actually work?* Because [Data Transfer Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) are a perfectly valid technique, and if that's all this is...

Comment: 2.  If you lack the words to describe the problem, then you don't have enough experience to refute your colleague's position.

Comment: 3.  If you have some working code you can post, post it to Code Review, and let them have a look at it.  Otherwise, this is just a wandering generality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Values that result from calculations are assigned to properties to be used inside several private methods throughout the class" doesn't sound like a self-respecting DTO to me. I do agree that a little more specificity would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like cargo cult reading of *Clean Code*.

Comment: Aside: Sounds like somebody hasn't actually read _Clean Code_ before bashing it. I just scanned it again, and could not find any place where it suggests "constructors shouldn't do work" (some examples in fact do perform work), and the suggested solution for avoiding too many parameters is to create a parameter object consolidating related groups of parameters, not bastardize your functions. And the book _does_ suggest  refactoring code to avoid temporal dependencies between methods. I think your bias against a few of his preferred code styles have colored your perception of the book.

Comment: @topomorto: You can put local properties or methods on a DTO that perform calculations and return values, and that doesn't make it any less of a DTO, really.  Dumb objects are still dumb objects.  Think: *Total Cell* in a spreadsheet, or something similar.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If it's doing calculations, it has responsibilities other than transferring data, which makes it less of a DTO according to what I think of as a DTO. *...a DTO does not have any behavior except for storage and retrieval of its own data...* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)). I appreciate that other definitions are probably available.

Comment: @topomorto: My sense is that the OP is already thinking too much about these sort of rules and definitions anyway.  He hasn't said anything at all about the actual functionality of the software (i.e. what real work does it do, and how well does it do that work) which, at the end of the day, is what really matters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As I said, I do agree that a little more specificity would be helpful. "what real work does it do, and how well does it do that work" covers a lot of what is important about software, but it doesn't cover maintainability, which is what might be most badly affected by the issues the OP mentions.

Comment: "Recently during a code review..." and then you did not discuss the issues with the co-worker but speculated on the answers you might get and turned to the internet for "ammunition". The most worrying part of this seems to be your shop's (or your personal) review process.

Comment: @EricKing I am not against the advice in the book. The criticism isn't directed against Clean code and I myself do agree that methods should preferably be short. I believe that long methods are usually symptoms to some design problem, but are not an objective measurement to bad code in itself.

Comment: @MartinMaat I am currently doing the code review. Or in other words: I have not approved the code yet. Yes I am looking for "ammunition". No I am not looking for ammunition for some purist personal opinions and I do not think something is wrong with looking for other people's opinions on the matters that I encountered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As someone who has read Clean Code and watched the Clean Coders series, multiple times, and often teach and coach other people in writing cleaner code, I can indeed vouch that your observations are correct - the metrics you point out are all mentioned in the book.

However, the book goes on to make other points which should also be applied alongside the guidelines that you pointed out. These were seemingly ignored in the code you're dealing with.
This may have happened because your colleague is still in the learning phase, in which case, as much as it is necessary to point out the *smells* of their code, it's good to remember that they're doing it in good will, learning and trying to write better code.

Clean Code does propose that methods should be short, with as few arguments possible. But along those guidelines, it proposes that we must folow **S**OLID principles, increase **cohesion** and reduce the **coupling**.

The **S** in SOLID stands for Single Responsibility Principle, which states that an object should be responsible for only one thing. "Thing" is not a very precise term, so the descriptions of this principle vary wildly. However, Uncle Bob, the author of Clean Code, is also the person who coined this principle, describing it as: "Gather together the things that change for the same reasons. Separate those things that change for different reasons." He goes on to say what he means with *reasons to change* [here](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt0M_OHKhQE) (a longer explanation here would be too much). If this principle was applied to the class you're dealing with, it is very likely that the pieces that deal with calculations would be separated from those that deal with holding state, by splitting the class in two or more, depending on how many *reasons to change* those calculations have.

Also, *Clean* classes should be **cohesive**, meaning that most of its methods use most of its attributes. As such, a maximally cohesive class is one where all methods use all of its attribute; as an example, in a graphical app you may have a `Vector` class with attributes `Point a` and `Point b`, where the only methods are `scaleBy(double factor)` and `printTo(Canvas canvas)`, both operating on both attributes. In contrast, a minimally cohesive class is one where each attribute is used in one method only, and never more than one attribute is used by each method. In average, a class presents non-cohesive "groups" of cohesive parts - i.e. a few methods use attributes `a`, `b` and `c`, while the rest use `c` and `d` -  meaning that if we split the class in two, we end up with two cohesive objects.

Finally, *Clean* classes should reduce **coupling** as much as possible. While there are many types of coupling worth discussing here, it seems the code at hand mainly suffers from **temporal coupling**, where, as you pointed out, the object's methods will only work as expected when they're called in the correct order. And like the two guidelines above-mentioned, the solutions to this usually involve splitting the class in two or more, **cohesive** objects. The splitting strategy in this case usually involves patterns like Builder or Factory, and in highly complex cases, State-Machines.

The TL;DR: The Clean Code guidelines that your colleague followed are good, but only when also following the remaining principles, practices and patterns mentioned by the book. The *Clean* version of the "class" you're seeing would be split into multiple classes, each with a single responsibility, cohesive methods and no temporal coupling. This is the context where small methods and little-to-no arguments make sense.

Comment: Both you and topo morto have written a good answer, but I can only accept one. I like that you addressed SRP, cohesiveness and coupling. These are useful terms that I can use in the code review. Splitting the object into smaller objects with their own responsibilities is obviously the way to go. One (non-constructor) method that initializes values onto a bunch of class properties is a dead giveaway that a new object ought to be returned. I should have seen that.

Comment: SRP is THE most important guideline; one ring to rule them all and all that. **Well done SRP naturally results in shorter methods.** Example: I have a front-facing class w/ only 2 public and about 8 non-public methods. None is more than ~ 3 lines; the whole class is about 35 LOC. But I wrote this class last! By the time all the underlying code was written this class essentially wrote itself and I did not have to, indeed could not, make the methods bigger. At no time did I say "I'm going to write these methods in 5 lines if it kills me." Every time you apply SRP it just happens.

Answer (score 14):

> It is my understanding that the class constructor is entirely responsible for the creation of a valid object and that its main task is the assignment of an object's (private) properties.

It's usually responsible for putting the object into an initial valid state, yes; other properties or methods may then change the state to another valid state.

> However, in the code that I encountered, most property values are
>   actually set by other methods than the constructor. Values that result
>   from calculations are assigned to properties to be used inside several
>   private methods throughout the class. The author seemingly uses class
>   properties as if they were global variables that should be accessible
>   throughout the class, instead of parameterizing these values to the
>   functions that need them. Additionally, the methods of the class
>   should be called in a specific order, because the class won't do much
>   otherwise.

As well as the problems with readability and maintainability that you allude to, it sounds like there are multiple stages of data flow/transform going on within the class itself, which may indicate that the class is falling foul of the single responsibility principle.

> suspect that this code has been inspired by the advice to keep
>   methods short (<=5 lines of code), to avoid large parameter lists (<3
>   parameters) and that constructors must not do work (such as performing
>   a calculation of some sort that is essential for the validity of the
>   object).

Following some coding guidelines whilst ignoring others often does lead to silly code. *If* we want to avoid a constructor doing work, for example, the sensible way would usually be to do the work before construction and pass the result of that work in to the constructor. (One argument for that approach might be that you're avoiding giving your class two responsibilities : the work of its initialisation, and its 'main job', whatever that is.)

In my experience, making classes and methods small is rarely something i have to bear in mind as a separate consideration - rather, it follows somewhat naturally from single responsibility.

> I would however rather propose to completely change the code, so that
>   the class becomes a blue print to an actual object, rather than a
>   series of methods which should be called (procedurally) in a specific
>   order.

You would probably be correct to do so. There's nothing wrong with writing straightforward procedural code; there is a problem in abusing the OO paradigm to write obfuscated procedural code.

> I believe there exists a rather clear distinction as to when to save a
>   value in a class property and when to put it into a parameter for a
>   different method to use - I don't really believe they can be
>   alternatives to one another. I am looking for the words for this
>   distinction.

*Usually*, you shouldn't be putting a value in a field as a way of passing it from one method to another; a value in a field should be a meaningful part of the state of an object at a given time. (I can think of some valid exceptions, but not ones where such methods are public or where there is an order dependency that a user of the class should be aware of)

Comment: upvote because: **1.** Emphasizing SRP. "... small methods... follow naturally"  **2.** Constructor purpose - valid state. **3.** "Following some coding guidelines whilst ignoring others." This is the Walking Dead of coding.

Answer (score 6):

You're most likely railing against the wrong pattern here.  Small functions and low arity are rarely problematic on their own.  The real issue here is the coupling that causes order dependence between functions, so look for ways to address that *without* throwing away the benefits of the small functions.

Code speaks louder than words.  People receive these sorts of corrections a lot better if you can actually do part of the refactoring and show the improvement, perhaps as a pair programming exercise.  When I do this, I often find it's more difficult than I thought to get the design right, balancing *all* the criteria.